# Incompatibility between babel spanish and russian?

Tags: amsmath, babel, spanish, russian

I am trying to compile an old document, created about three years ago. Then it worked fine with pdflatex and TL2019 or TL2020 (I'm not sure which one). Now with pdflatex and TL2022 I get errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \tg already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

and the same for `\arctg` and `\cosec` commands.

I isolated the problem (or so I think), and it arises when I put together `babel` with Spanish (as main language) and Russian, and `amsmath`. I suppose the problem is that both languages are defining the same macros and somehow that produces the errors, but I have no idea how to prevent them.

My M(non)WE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=spanish,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Una sección}
En cirílico \foreignlanguage{russian}{Лев Семёнович Понтр\'{я}гин},
y en alfabeto occidental Lev Semënovi\v{c} Pontrâ\'{g}in.
\end{document}
```

Remark. It works if I remove any of these items:

- `amsmath` package.
- `main` option for Spanish.
- Russian language (and the cyrillic text).

I also changed the loading order of the packages, but to no avail.

Comment: For the same reason, one cannot use `chemformula` with a few language modules that define `\ch` for the hyperbolic cosine and offer no way to prevent this.

Comment: @egreg, so there is no way to work with both languages with a recent LaTeX distribution? :O

Comment: I guess that this is something that Javier Bezos should sort out. However, if you just need to typeset some words in Russian, you can remove `russian` from the options to `babel` and add `\babelprovide{russian}`. By the way, the accent over `g` is wrong.

Comment: @egreg, indeed, I only need a couple or Russian names, but this way the cyrillic doesn't show

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug that has been hidden for a couple of decades.

Both the Spanish and Russian modules for `babel` want to define “local” math operators, because of tradition.

In the past, with your setup, the Spanish definitions would silently override the Russian ones, but recently `russianb.ldf` replaced

```
\def\tg{\mathop{\operator@font tg}\nolimits}
```

with

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsopn}
  {%
    [...]
    \DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}%
    [...]
  }{%
    [...]
    \DeclareRobustCommand\tg{\mathop{\operator@font tg}\nolimits}%
    [...]
  }
```

which would be a good thing (contrary to what the module for Spanish does, ignoring whether `amsmath` is loaded or not), provided no other language module defines `\tg`. Unfortunately, `spanish.ldf` does.

While Spanish offers a (not really friendly) way to disable the “language local” operators, Russian doesn't.<sup>1</sup>
In my opinion both should bind the definitions in `\extras<language>`: it would be quite strange to get “lím” in a Russian part of the document, for instance.

Is there a way out? I can see none for general bilingual typesetting. But if you just need `russian` for typesetting some words in Russian (names, for instance), you can avoid loading all of `russian.ldf` and just ask for basic support.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=spanish]{babel}
\babelprovide{russian}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Una sección}
En cirílico \foreignlanguage{russian}{Лев Семёнович Понтр\'{я}гин},
y en alfabeto occidental Lev Semënovi\v{c} Pontrâgin.
\end{document}
```

[image]

An interim workaround if you're tied to Debian based TeX Live:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=spanish]{babel}
\babelprovide{russian}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rus}[1]{{%
  \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}%
}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Una sección}
En cirílico \rus{Лев Семёнович Понтр\'{я}гин},
y en alfabeto occidental Lev Semënovi\v{c} Pontrâgin.
\end{document}
```

**Footnote.**
<sup>1</sup> In order to disable the Spanish style operators one can do

```
\makeatletter\let\es@operators\relax\makeatother
```

but this isn't helpful in the case at hand, because it removes everything about Spanish style math operators. If the document had Russian as main language, this would work, but the converse fails and there's no real way to make Russian and Spanish style operators to coexist in one and the same document. Currently no way to make a bilingual document, actually.

Comment: This is just what I need but I'm still getting errors: `Command \CYRL unavailable in encoding T1. ...�в Семёнович Понтрягин}` and many others like this. Perhaps I need a more recent update?

Comment: @JuanCastaño Yes, you need to update to TeX Live 2022.

Comment: This is what I have: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)`

Comment: @JuanCastaño I added a workaround for your situation.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for all the effort!!!

Comment: @egreg Two mistakes wrt `spanish`. (1) “Unfortunately, both do it in a global fashion, not bounded by language changes”: that’s wrong, redefinitions in `spanish` are language dependent. (2) “Neither language module offers a package option for disabling the definition”: not as package option, but with `\let\es@operators\relax` in the preample, which is even documented in the manual (arguably, a `@`-command is not a good idea, but they can be certainly disabled).

Comment: @JavierBezos Possibly, but that's not a solution anyway, because with `main=spanish` one *does* want Spanish operators.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I don’t understand your point.

Comment: @JavierBezos Suppose you do `\makeatletter\let\es@operators\relax\makeatother`. Then at begin document, `russianb.ldf` enters the scene and defines the operators the Russian way, which is not the same as the Spanish way. So in a document with Spanish as main language you get Russian style operators.

Comment: @egreg Oh, well, yes, but my point here is that `spanish` does provide a way to disable the operators.

Comment: @JavierBezos That's good (although the interface is horrible), but not really useful either for the problem at hand.

Comment: @egreg I just wanted to point out your answer contains a wrong claim and that there is another claim which, while not technically incorrect, it‘s incomplete.

Comment: @JavierBezos I fixed the “wrong” claim, but the bulk of the matter remains unsolved.

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to @egreg’s answer [*edit:* which has some inaccuracies], and if you want the changes in `spanish`, here is a workaround. It first saves and disables the redefinitions done by `spanish` with the first implicit `\selectlanguage{spanish}`, and then, after `russian` has defined `\tg`, it enables them and selects `spanish` again. This minimal example prints “lím tg lim tg lím tg”.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,spanish]{babel}

\let\savemathspanish\mathspanish
\let\mathspanish\relax
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mathspanish\savemathspanish
  \selectlanguage{spanish}}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\lim\tg$ \foreignlanguage{russian}{$\lim\tg$} $\lim\tg$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, It works perfectly. Gracias, Javier!!!